# Using an if statement within a for loop- Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, for-loop

I'm having trouble using an if statement inside a for loop in excel vba. The output of the debugger is not what I expect. I can post the full code of what I am trying to accomplish, but I think I have narrowed it down to what I don't understand. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim i As Integer

For i = 9 To 60 Step 3

If Cells(i, "DR").Value < Cells(i, "EB").Value Then
    Debug.Print i & "-ifloopstart"
    Cells(i, "DR").Value = 999999
    Debug.Print i & "-ifloopend"
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

The output of the debugger is:

```
9-ifloopstart
33-ifloopstart
51-ifloopstart
51-ifloopend
33-ifloopend
9-ifloopend
```

However, I expected:

```
9-ifloopstart
9-ifloopend
33-ifloopstart
33-ifloopend
51-ifloopstart
51-ifloopend
```

Can someone explain how this works? It seems to be looping back to the beginning of the if statement instead of finishing the if statement. How can I modify the code to get the output I expect? I've been struggling with this for hours and it seems so simple :( .

Comment: updating the sheet will again trigger the event code, so you should use `Application.EnableEvents=False` before making any changes.  Set back to True when done...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time the worksheet is updated with `Cells(i, "DR").Value = 999999`, `Worksheet_Change` gets called again.

Think of it this way. Each time that above code gets called, you modify a cell,  which triggers the worksheet change method again.

So you are effectively nesting three calls of this function:

- called once, with i = 9

  - called again, with i = 33

    - called again, with i = 51
    - finishes i = 51 call
  - finishes i = 33 call
- finishes i = 9 call

VBA then goes backwards from each of these to get back to the first time your method was run.

Edit: as [Tim says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410612/using-an-if-statement-within-a-for-loop-excel-vba#comment27043976_18410612) you can disable this with `Application.EnableEvents=False`

Comment: wow, big thanks to everyone who answered!... I've been going crazy here.