# VBA Array issue

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am currently trying to input data from an export sheet from MS Project. I have produced the data on worksheet1 and I am attempting to reproduce what I have created in an excel page.

I am at the early stages and I have written some code. I have looked up the error and I cannot see where I am going wrong. To start with, i just want to input a sub section of the data into an array so I can manipulate it later on.

The debug is highlighting the following line:

If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 9).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).Value Then

I am a C++ programmer so I thought my array manipulation was ok but this is my second day on VBA so take it easy on me!

Code Below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Dim Arr(2, 11) As Variant

j = 5

For i = 1 To 10

If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 9).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).Value Then Arr(0, i) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Value And Arr(1, i) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6).Value And Arr(2, i) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 7).Value

Next i

MsgBox ("Value in Array index 2,2 : " & Arr(2, 2))

End Sub
```

Comment: If you need some knowledge on how arrays work in VBA perhaps this site is of help: http://www.homeandlearn.org/multidimensional_arrays.html

Comment: I thought similarly to C++ that arrays are defined as arr(x,y) however the first array is always arr(0,0) therefore effectually x+1 and y+1?

Comment: Even with defining the array within the helpful link as arr(1 to 3, 1 to 11) I am still getting the same error code on the same line. The array is not highlighted but there is a subscript error 9

Comment: You can begin a new line after THEN, so put the rest on a new line, then it becomes easier to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: If I do that it is giving a syntax error. I think I am missing some syntax within the body of the For and Next. Not sure what though, will keep looking.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410612/using-an-if-statement-within-a-for-loop-excel-vba - Relevant?

Comment: Oh btw, the default of the array is to start at 0. I am used to make them start at 1, but I manually input that. My answer was adapted to the latter, will update that now.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Dim Arr(2, 11) As Variant

j = 5

For i = 1 To 10

If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 9).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).Value Then
    Arr(0, i) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Value
    Arr(1, i) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6).Value
    Arr(2, i) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 7).Value
End If

Next i

MsgBox ("Value in Array index 2,2 : " & Arr(2, 2))

End Sub
```

The "IF" statement didn't need those "ANDs" for when the statement is true. That might have been one of the issues.  In VB (not sure about C++), when your IF statement is TRUE, everything after `Then` will occur, until the `End If` (or `ElseIf`), no need to say "do this, AND do this, AND do this...", it's just "Do this, this, this, this".

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. It still however doesn't work with the same error flagging. I increased the range of the array to 1000 to try and encompass all lines as I thought it was missing the data. Still not working with Subscript error 9. Can you look in my earlier comment and as I have a feeling it is to do with adding range data to arrays but I am not sure why making Application.EnableEvents=False would help. Will start looking it up

Comment: What data do you have in your sheets? I can run the code above without any errors.  What does the error say? I see it's a syntax error, but more specifically what does it say?  And it highlights on the `If Worksheets(...` line? or some other point? (Hit "Debug" when the error shows up).

Comment: Ok... I was being an idiot. This now works. My worksheet was renamed so couldn't be called

Comment: Ah, great! Yeah, I have done the same thing, so no worries :P

Answer (score 0):

```
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 9).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).Value Then
Arr(0, i) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Value
Arr(1, i) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6).Value
Arr(2, i) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 7).Value

End If
```

Replace your long line of IF code with this. You also forgot to close your IF statement, and the AND statements are not needed, it just executes all code after THEN until it hits and END IF

Comment: This code worked for me. So if you are getting errors it probably has to do with the rest of the code this is part of.

Comment: This is a standalone piece of code at the moment. I am building the rest of it once I can fill the array.